# Input Dialog [Information Needed]

Tags: java, string, swing, input, output

So I have a program that launches an input dialog when I click a button. What I need help on is that once I gather the information from the input dialog and they are gone, I press the Enter key and the input dialogs re-appear. Why?

Also, How can I have it so that if the input dialog is left empty, it comes out as an error and then repeats until it is not empty?

---

```
public static String fn;
public static String sn;

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
    sn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second name");

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    text.setText("Welcome " + fn + " " + sn + ".");
    b.setVisible(false);
    text.setVisible(true);
    text.setBounds(140,0,220,20);
    text.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    text.setEditable(false);
    text.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    writeToFile();
}

public BingoHelper(){
    super("BINGO");
    add(text);
    text.setVisible(false);
    add(b);
    this.add(pnlButton);
    pnlButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //pnlButton.add(b);+
    b.setVisible(true);
    b.setBounds(145,145,145,20);
    //b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
    b.addActionListener(this);
    b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    rootPane.setDefaultButton(b);
}
```

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive responsibility of the LayoutManager.

Comment: When you gather the input, and input dialog gone, the button gain focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `rootPane.setDefaultButton` you are specifying the button which is activated by the Enter key.

To prevent a JOptionPane from closing when the input is not acceptable, create an actual JOptionPane instance, then create your own button and specify it as an option.  The button's Action or ActionListener must call the JOptionPane's `setValue` method:

```
final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("What is your first name?",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
optionPane.setWantsInput(true);

Action accept = new AbstractAction("OK") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object value = optionPane.getInputValue();
        if (value != null && !value.toString().isEmpty()) {
            // This dismisses the JOptionPane dialog.
            optionPane.setValue(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        }
    }
};

Object acceptButton = new JButton(accept);
optionPane.setOptions(new Object[] { acceptButton, "Cancel" });
optionPane.setInitialValue(acceptButton);

// Waits until dialog is dismissed.
optionPane.createDialog(null, "First Name").setVisible(true);

if (!Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION).equals(optionPane.getValue())) {
    // User canceled dialog.
    return;
}

String fn = optionPane.getInputValue().toString();
```